# How to post score on facebook fan's page from iphone game app using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to find a way to post score on  Facebook fan's page  from my iPhone game  application using cocos2d, but can't find a way to do it.I used graph API but no use.Can anyone provide me some information?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 6 facebook integration is very easy.Apple release api for facebook. refer this link http://prassan-warrior.blogspot.in/2012/11/integration-of-social-networks-into-ios.html

Comment: I referred FBfriendimagepost in https://github.com/KRadix/CommonUtility/downloads.It worked fine.